# How do determine if three 2D geo points are a triangle?

Tags: go, geospatial, geos

I have three geo points with latitude and longitude coordinates. How do determine that they are forming a triangle? They can lie on the same diagonal line and it will be a line.

A simple coordinate comparison is not suitable for a diagonal line, because all coordinates will be different.

Comment: test whether the three points are collinear. if they are not, they form a triangle